# react-draggable not working with custom components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-draggable

How can I get a custom component to drag?

The following works when clicked

```
import React from 'react';
import { DraggableCore } from 'react-draggable';

export default class Hello extends React.Component {

  onStart = () => {
    console.log('here');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DraggableCore
        onStart={this.onStart}
      >
        <h1>Drag me!</h1>
      </DraggableCore>
    );
  }
}
```

and this does not

```
import React from 'react';
import { DraggableCore } from 'react-draggable';

class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>{this.props.children}</h1>
    );
  }
}

export default class Hello extends React.Component {

  onStart = () => {
    console.log('here');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DraggableCore
        onStart={this.onStart}
      >
        <Test>Drag me!</Test>
      </DraggableCore>
    );
  }
}
```

with the only difference being that instead of `h1` being used directly, it now uses custom component `Test`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ev9iyu?file=Hello.js

I have tried forwarding the ref. I have also tried wrapping it in a `Fragment`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your component with a `div` inside of `DraggableCore`:

```
<DraggableCore onStart={this.onStart}>
  <div>
    <Test>Drag me!</Test>
  </div>
</DraggableCore>
```

Comment: What about when I am dragging an SVG <rect />? Putting the <rect /> straight into the <DraggableCore> works but I want to encapsulate it!

Comment: This may ruin the positioning.

Answer (score 2):

I'm super late to the game here but I hope this helps someone. You have to give your component a rest prop. You need to do this because DraggableCore copies the component and puts several event listeners on the component. Look at the render of DraggableCore. https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-draggable/blob/master/lib/DraggableCore.js. Your component needs to be able to receive these event listeners.

```
const Test = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <div {...rest}>{children}</div>
  )
}

const Hello = () => {
  const handleStart = () => console.log('here');

  return (
    <DraggableCore
      onStart={handleStart}
    >
      <Test>Drag me!</Test>
    </DraggableCore>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, this isn't correct. You haven't passed any props through to `Test` in your example, so `rest` will always be empty, also you can't spread react props onto a div - you will get an error in the console explaining that they are not dom attributes

Comment: The given answer is correct for this question

Comment: My proposal worked for me. I passed {...rest} to a div on a custom component and it worked